# How to correctly allocate a buffer for fuse readdir()?

Tags: c++, c, fuse

While implementing a FUSE filesystem using a C++ wrapper, I got stuck on `readdir()` function. Here is the function which I am mimmicking from `passthrough.c`:

```
static int xmp_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
               off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi,
               enum fuse_readdir_flags flags)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *de;

    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;
    (void) flags;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if (dp == NULL)
        return -errno;

    void* mybuf = malloc(10000);

    while ((de = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        struct stat st;
        memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st));
        st.st_ino = de->d_ino;
        st.st_mode = de->d_type << 12;
        if (filler(mybuf, de->d_name, &st, 0, 0))
            break;
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

(source: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough.c):

My filesystem requires that I allocate the buffer locally, so instead of using the parameterized `void *buf`, I tried to create a local buffer like so:

```
void* buf = malloc(10000);
```

No matter how large of a buffer I allocate, I am always getting a segmentation fault when `filler()` is called. As a control, I have tried to similarly allocate a local buffer in the fully working `passthrough.c` example, and I still received a segmentation fault error. This reaffirmed that my problem lies in the buffer allocation.

What is the proper way to allocate a buffer to be used in the `filler()` fuse function?

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: It's not an issue with buffer size. It's probably an issue with your `filler()` code.

Comment: @JL2210 ```filler()```  is not mine, it is part of the fuse library. It is defined as ```fill_dir()``` in ```fuse.c```. The function also works properly in the ```passthrough.c``` example I mentioned

Comment: @LeenA Where'd you create the local buffer?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This code was taken directly from the libfuse ```pasthrough.c``` example I provided as a source. The void casts are there so that the compiler does not complain about unused parameters.

Comment: `buf` is also not yours. It's the private context of `filler`. You step on it by allocating over it and then when `filler` de-references a structure that has been run over there's seg fault. See here https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/f0e08cc700d629da2d46def8b620b0ed858cc0d9/lib/fuse.c#L3639

Comment: @JL2210 sorry for the confusion, I have edited the code to show where I allocated the local buffer.

Comment: Still, filler expects to get his original `buf`. You can't override it. What you should do is write you're own `my_filler` which get's `my_buf, buf, filler` and inside it calls `filler(buf)`

Comment: @OrenKishon I am using an RPC library to call ```readdir()``` remotely, and it prevents me from using the original ```buf```. Is there a way to create and use a local buffer?

Comment: I didn't quite understand "call readdir() remotely"

Comment: @OrenKishon My program has a client-server model. I invoke the functions (such as readdir()) on my local machine and they are executed on a remote server. For example, when I invoke a function such as ```mkdir()```, it creates a directory in a path I specify on the server, and not in my local directory.

Comment: Anyway, where ever fuse is running, `buf` is a private context, as `this` in C++. It not for you to mangle with.

Comment: @LeenA: How does the RPC library “prevent” using the `buf` parameter?  Does it allocate that space for you?

Comment: @DavisHerring the RPC library uses Protobuffers and allows only certain types to be sent over its function calls (a list of the allowed types is under "Scalar Value Types": https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3). So, I cannot send the original void* buf, and I have to locally allocate it.

Comment: Is only the internal `readdir` call done using RPC? I understand you readdir a remote location. But isn't `filler()` called localy after `readdir` has returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use the provided buffer *buf like

```
 if (filler(buf, de->d_name, &st, 0, 0))
        break;
```

and it will work just fine. It's not necessary to create the buffer your self.

This is how I use it and it works just fine.